# Add 3 images to the first post cross browser solution

Tags: image, css

I need to have a banner image for the first post but it needs to expand vertically because posts will vary in the amount of content. currently I have this in y loop.php

```
<article class="post <?php echo !is_single() ? "preview" : "" ?> <?php echo $count == 0 ? "first" : "" ?> <?php echo !is_home() ? "full" : "" ?>">
```

I cannot attached the image since I do not have the correct reputation on this site!

However, the image is a banner that will wrap the edges of the main content div. I sliced it into 3 separate images-- a top, middle, and bottom-- thinking I could just use `:before` and `:after` in my css but this will not work in IE7 or 8 for me.

My class currently for the first post is "first" but I would need to add a top and bottom to this I think but I would like the best solution and I am too much of a newbie.

I feel I am really stuck and need some help. Let me know if you need more to go off of I can see what I can do about getting an image on this site to show you what needs to happen here.

Comment: This appears to be a pure CSS and/or markup (HTML) question and doesn't appear to be WordPress specific at all.

Comment: It is and my solution is to do this:

    `<?php
    if (!is_single() & $count == 0):
    ?>
    <div class="firsttop"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>`

and to have after the loop code for the post.

    `<?php
    if (!is_single() & $count == 0):
    ?>
    <div class="firstbottom"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>`

I have answered my own question but i was looking at it from the wrong angle. Thank you for everyone who looked at this.

Comment: You originally posted on [wordpress.se] where pure CSS questions are off-topic. If that is your solution, post it in the "Answer" box, not in a comment.

Comment: I am not able to for 8 hours it says so i wanted to avoid more answers for this i can delete it but it may help someone later on if they have a similar issue Up to you lmk.

Comment: Ok the issue is not solved I still get the two images showing on the authors bio page. Is there a way to stop the divs from displaying if its the authors page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your theme uses `body_class` as it should then there should be class named `author` attached to the `<body>` tag for author archives. You can use that to simple not display the `div`s-- via `display:none`.

You almost had the PHP solution though, if I understand you. You need [`is_author`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) instead of `is_single`

```
<?php if (!is_author() && $count == 0): ?> 
    <div class="firsttop"></div> 
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- more Loop code -->   
<?php if (!is_author() & $count == 0): ?> 
    <div class="firstbottom"></div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

If that isn't it, I don't know you mean by "the author's page".